# Delete folder in Azure blob storage

Tags: c#, .net, azure-blob-storage

I need help with deleting folders from Azure blob storage. I need to delete folders that have about 500,000 stocks in each. I currently do it by taking a list of the filenames and feeding them in, but that takes too long.

Is there an option to delete the entire folder rather than each file one by one?

I've tried Azure Storage Explorer and it deletes them significantly faster there, but I haven't found a way to use `azcopy` in C#. I had the option to run `azcopy` commands or delete the entire folder instead of each file one by one.

Comment: Have you looked here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-remove#examples?

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't found a way to use `azcopy` in C#. I had the option to run
> `azcopy` commands or delete the entire folder instead of each file one by one.

First, you need to download the **`AzCopy`** tool from this [MS-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#download-azcopy) in your local environment.

In my Azure blob storage, I have a folder with the name **`Sample`** with some files like the below:

**Portal:**

[image]

You can use the below C# code to remove the folder from the container using with **`AzCopy`** tool.

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string AccountUrl = "https://<storageaccount name>.blob.core.windows.net";
        string SasToken = "?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=co&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2023-12-06T17:10:49Z&st=2023-12-06T09:10:49Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxx"; //your-sas-token
        string Container = "demo";
        string Directory = "sample";

        RemovefolderWithAzCopy(AccountUrl, SasToken, Container, Directory);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void RemovefolderWithAzCopy(string AccountUrl, string SasToken, string Container, string Directory)
    {
        string BlobUrl = $"{AccountUrl}/{Container}/{Directory}{SasToken}";
        string azCopyCommand = $"azcopy rm \"{BlobUrl}\" --recursive=true";
        ExecuteCommand(azCopyCommand);

        Console.WriteLine($"Deleted Directory Successfully!!!");
    }

    static void ExecuteCommand(string command)
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/c {command}";
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        process.Start();

        // You can optionally read the output if needed
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(output);

        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
 INFO: Any empty folders will be processed because source and destination both support folders
INFO: azcopy: A newer version 10.22.0 is available to download


Job 4701xxxxx has started
Log file is located at: xxxx.log

100.0 %, 15 Done, 0 Failed, 0 Pending, 0 Skipped, 15 Total,


Job 4701xxxxxe summary
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.0334
Number of File Transfers: 15
Number of Folder Property Transfers: 0
Total Number of Transfers: 15
Number of Transfers Completed: 15
Number of Transfers Failed: 0
Number of Transfers Skipped: 0
TotalBytesTransferred: 72721
Final Job Status: Completed


Deleted Directory Successfully!!!
Press any key to exit...
```

[image]

After executing the code, I checked in the portal it was deleted successfully.

**Reference:**

[azcopy remove | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-remove#examples)